# Subgroups and normal subgroups of $D_5$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, dihedral-groups

I have worked out the elements in $D_5$ (has order 10) and the conjugacy classes

I want to find all the subgroups of $D_5$ and the normal subgroups

By Lagrange I know the subgroups must be of sizes 1,2,5 or 10
Obviously the trivial ones are e and $D_5$ but I am not sure how to find the others( I know they must all contain the identity)

Secondly which ones of these would be normal? I am guessing it has something to do with the conjugacy classes

Thanks

Comment: Hints: If $G$ is any group, and $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ with $[G:H] =2,$ then $H$ is normal. If $K$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ with $|K| = 2,$ then $K \leq Z(G).$

Comment: Thanks! The only subgroup with index 2 has order 5, so I guess I should just calculate all the elements of order 5, and these form the normal subgroup of order 5. Why would k be a subgroup of the centre of a group?

Comment: Because if $k$ is the nontrivial element and $g\in G$, then $gkg^{-1} = k$ because $K$ is normal, so $gkg^{-1}k^{-1} = kk^{-1} = 1$.

Comment: See http://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CEcQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.uconn.edu%2F~kconrad%2Fblurbs%2Fgrouptheory%2Fdihedral2.pdf&ei=qg1-U6zjFOfh4QTNrYCIAQ&usg=AFQjCNExft8iJ2-3luuioMN8NO5LaOhJVg&cad=rja, Theorem 3.1

Comment: Thanks guys. I am just calculating the orders of the elements. In general in Dn s it true to say that r^k has order lcm(n,k) and sr^k has order 2 (since it is a reflection)?